# Minecraft PE can't connect to my home WiFi consistently

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have had this issue for a while, and it is driving me crazy. So, I play Minecraft PE on an IPad Mini 4, and I cannot stay logged into Xbox Live while on the WiFi in my house. When I go to a different place to play on the WiFi, it works. At home, it just tries to log into Xbox Live forever, and I can’t play my worlds. Help!

Comment: 2 questions: What verison of PE are you currently on? What internet type is at home? (NAT Type, and the provider)

Comment: I have the latest version, 1.11.2. The internet is provided by our town’s utility company. I don’t know what NAT type is.

Comment: NAT type is the connection type you have, like whether you can connect and do all things online such as hosting a multiplayer game or talking in a voice chat. 'Our Town's Utility Company' Doesn't really help. If you could please name it? What is the name of the WiFi when you login on your devices? (E.G. BTHUB-5.87876)

Comment: I’m not entirely sure, but it’s not open. Waverly Utilities is the network. The WiFi name is our last name, which I don’t feel comfortable naming online.

Comment: Actually, I do think that it is open, but Minecraft is blocked in some way.

Comment: No, being unable to name the WiFi name is fine, I just thought it might help us figure out the internet provider's name. If your NAT type is open, it should work. Have you ever had trouble with this before?

Comment: Do you have problems with other things on iPad while on your home WiFi? Like streaming services? (Netflix, Hulu, etc, anything that requires a constant connection?)  It kinda sounds like it's a device connectivity issue and not specific to your game.

Comment: It’s only Minecraft that’s having any problems. I can even get into the Xbox live app on the WiFi, but not Minecraft.